# mapr installation with mapr-setup script

Tags: hadoop, mapr

I'm facing issue when installing the `MapR` installer. It is unable to read from the repository. Please check below link for detailed error. Let me know how to overcome this.

http://justpaste.it/q6vl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to clean the repo cache. If it is on RedHat run the command "yum clean all" and attemp the install again.